# How to add special character for the big list?

Tags: notepad++, edit, words

I'd like to make a big dictionary with jquery auto suggest.
I found a great site where the words are collected in one place.
The site URL:
[dictionary](http://www.magyarhelyesiras.hu/gyakori_hibak.php)
Only problem is this too much time for me.
So every word must be look like this:
,'word', thats becouse my function requires this form.

I show my function with some words:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var elements = ['span', 'div', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3','a','blockqoute','font','p','strong',];
var words = ['apple', 'google', 'facebook',    'github','azért','mert','szerintem','te','abszolút','addig,','eddig','afféle','agresszív','  ahhoz','ajánlólevél','akkor   sem','alakítás','állapotban','az','általában','általános','ez','nem szóltam','semmit','semmi','amíg','amiatt','az, hogy','azért is, csak azért is','azt mondom','bátorít','egyetért','hülye','1-gyel','1-je','1-jén','2-t','3-mal','4-gyel','5-tel','6-tal','amíg','azt is','becsszóra','hogy','bensőséges','bírom',' bírja','bírod','bizonyos','bizony','bizonyítvány','bonyolít','borítékol','link','dagadt','deformálódik','degradál','dehogyis!','demagóg','didereg',' bedől','efféle','egész alakos','egyértelmű','egypárszor ','ehhez',' éjszaka','kész','vagyok','intelligens','intelligencia','intelligens','irigyel','irigyled','irkál','irtózatos','Ivettel','január 1-jétől','kínál','kitűnő','körül','lehetséges volna-e','lejjebb','Linuxszal','megszűnik','mentesít','mind','felesleges','mindegy','viszont','mindjárt','modell','muszáj','műfaj','youtube','youtube-on','nagyképű','nagyobb','nagyszámú','naná','nem is tudom','nem is tudtam','nyilván','nyírfa','nyitva tartás','nyitvatartási idő','nyugdíjas','objektív','őrület','például','pénz','perdít','pontosan','pórnép','rosszkedvű','rosszullét','rosszul','röhejes','rövid','rövid távú','saját','sajátom','saját kezűleg','segítek',];
```

So the question is how to add necessary character for every words,like notepad++ find and replace option.

Comment: Now i have a vote down,why? This is not a good question?

Comment: Now 2 votedown, why? This question is so bad?
Every one know the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not too clear to me what you actually want to do, but if I got it right you need to add around all words in a text file using in Notepad++, a single-quote.

So, in the Find-Replace dialogue do the following.
Find:

```
\b(.+?)\b
```

Replace:

```
'$1'
```

And don't forget to check firstly the "Regular expression" radio button.

Let me know if that's what you asked for.

Comment: This not working on notepad++ becouse this "\b(.+?)\b" not exist on list.
That's becouse i can't replace...
Otherwise i need add this carachters for words:
,"", you can see how it works the function.
Example some words for better understanding:
"apple", "google","facebook" 
But the list not have this character and this is a problem,becouse the funcction not working without this characters

Comment: I'm sure you forgot to select the "Regular expression" radio button as I told you! It's in the bottom left corner of the Replace dialogue. Check again!

Comment: Nope, you can see in here: http://www.kephost.com/view3.php?filename=a1_2013_10_15_u3g89t3xl6.png

Comment: Exactly! As I told you again, you have first to select the "Regular expression" button!!! From what I can see in this image, in Hungarian it is translated "Mintaillesztessel".

Comment: http://www.kephost.com/view3.php?filename=a1_2013_10_15_u3g89t3xl6.png
See?
Nothing happend

Comment: Adam, please read again my last comment and see this picture: http://i40.tinypic.com/4ieyrd.png

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to help you, because what I suggested, works for me. Maybe you could try to update your Notepad++ because from the screenshot it seems to me as a quite old version (latest is 6.5) and then try again the regular expression.

Comment: Thank you I not get notification for upgrade :S
I try upgrade now, i writeback after.

Comment: http://i44.tinypic.com/9ht4k9.png Nothing heppen.
I have windows 8,you think this is a problem?
Here the list,if  working for you please do it me...
http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/word.txt

Comment: Can you please go to the "About" and let us know the version number of your Notepad++? The version of Windows don't matter. Here's the result of the regular expression http://pastebin.com/SVzGtk2K

Comment: Sure here the printscreen for the fresh version:
http://i43.tinypic.com/s2xqc7.png
Thx the list!
THis very big help for me :)
If you find out why not working this "regular" method,please let me know